# multi-class multi-dimensional label classification in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, multilabel-classification

If I have a binary classification task, the last layer of a neural network should be:

```
output= tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

If the classification problem is multi-class, label is scalar and one out of k discrete value, I usually encode the scalar label into a k-dimensional one-hot representation and modify

```
output= tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(k,activation='softmax')(x)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

If I have a binary classification task with multiple k binary targets, I would modify as:

```
output= tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(k,activation='sigmoid')(x)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

However, I still can not figure out what is the correct network design when I have multiple outputs and multiple categories per output.
e.g. [[0,1],[7,2],..]

Comment: You mean multiple outputs _and_ multiple categories per output?

Comment: yes. can you help?

Comment: Is what you need any different than this? https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#models-with-multiple-inputs-and-outputs